# Identity Delegation across WCF services with WIF 4.5

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security, wif, claims-based-identity

I am building an application where a client makes a call to a WCF service, say Service1, to perform some action. This WCF service, Service1, in turn makes call to another WCF service, say Service2, to perform a sub action.

I am using WIF with .NET 4.5. My client is running under logged-in user account and my WCF services are running under Local Service a/c. I have configured WIF to use Windows authentication and Windows principal. I am not using any STS.

WCF Service1 gets the client's Windows principal and identity from ClaimsPrincipal.Current. But the Service2 gets Local Service account principal and identity. This is working on trusted sub-system principal. But I need client's identity, the logged in user's identity passed to Service2.

I want to know how I can configure my application to use WIF identity delegation that is, how I can pass the client's principal across my WCF services?

Answer (score 0):

It's [**the Double-Hop Problem**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx). Your first WCF service tries to run a query to 2nd WCF service using the account under it's running with. You have to impersonate your call on 1st WCF service. Here is an examples: [WCF impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650591.aspx), [ASP](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2004/09/22/232967.aspx)